# Thunderbird spends an hour downloading every time I start it

Tags: ubuntu, thunderbird

I have just set up thunderbird on ubuntu 20.04 to use my work exchange setup (that also needs OAuth 2 and MFA). It set up ok but I have two problems.

- After spending an hour or so downloading and synchronising it had downloaded all my mail folders correctly. But it doesn't seem to give me any new emails when they arrive.
- I quit thunderbird and restarted. It is now spending another hour downloading and synchronising although it has now got my new emails that arrived since I first installed it.

I don't know if it matters but in the xterm I started thunderbird from there are a lot of messages including "console.warn: Lightning: No unique email address for lookup!" and "console.warn: Lightning: Parsing failed for parts of the item (while this is considered to be a minor issue, we continue processing the item):
" which appear repeatedly.

Comment: is it POP3, IMAP or what?

Comment: @Andra Microsoft exchange. There are three options in thunderbird and that is one of them.  (not POP or IMAP)